# Is it possible to use array version of Perls system function to return immediately?

Tags: linux, perl

Is it possible to use the array version of perls `system` command (i.e. the version that takes the first element as the command and the rest of the array as the cmd arguments) while also spawning a new process with Linux so that the `system` command returns immediately e.g. to run a command like:

```
mycmd arg1 arg2 &
```

I've tried using `system( ('mycmd', 'arg1', 'arg2', '&') )` but it just interprets the ampersand literally as a third argument.

I know I can just pass the whole command as a scalar to `system` but I'm specifically wondering if it's possible to use the array version because the parameters for this command will originate from user options in a CGI script.

Comment: [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) forks a new process and execs your shell command there. Any arguments you pass in the shell command get executed in this other process so while you may pass an `&` to make it work in the background; It is really the background of this other process that was started not your current one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `&` part of the shell command tells the shell to run the process in the background, so bypassing the shell by using the multi-arg form of `system` makes no sense.

Solution 1: Quote using String::ShellQuote.

```
use String:ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );
system(shell_quote('mycmd', 'arg1', 'arg2').' &');
```

Solution 2: Quote using shell interpolation.

```
system('sh', '-c', '"$@" &', 'sh', 'mycmd', 'arg1', 'arg2');
```

Solution 3: Launch the program in the background yourself.

```
use IPC::Open3 qw( open3 );

{
   open(local *CHILD_IN, '<', '/dev/null') or die $!;
   local $SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE';
   open3(
      '<&CHILD_IN', '>&STDOUT', '>&STDERR',
      'mycmd', 'arg1', 'arg2',
   );
}
```

Comment: None of these solutions will work for me. I can run the command and it does return immediately, but the script still waits at the end for the underlying command to complete. I posted a separate question which hopefully is more appropriate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28126351/end-perl-script-without-waiting-for-system-call-to-return?noredirect=1#comment44625794_28126351

Comment: I realized that my problem is not specifically or solely a Perl problem, because the solutions here work if I run my perl script directly from a terminal. Although my web server and CGI script setup causes "something" to wait until the underlay system command has completed before returning a response to the web request, which is what the other Q is about.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have no interest in the fate of the executed program you can use fork/exec. And you're on Linux which allows using `$SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE'` to avoid waiting on the child process.

```
sub background { 
    local $SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE';
    # fork and then exec if we are the child
    exec(@_) or die($!) unless fork; 
}
background( 'mycmd', 'arg1', 'arg2' );
```

Comment: This solution will not work for me. I can run the command and it does return immediately, but the script still waits at the end for the underlying command to complete. I posted a separate question which hopefully is more appropriate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28126351/end-perl-script-without-waiting-for-system-call-to-return?noredirect=1#comment44625794_28126351